# Sort objects by timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following elasticSearch query to get the user events and sort them by timestamp :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "term": {
          "userId": 56
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "size": 9999,
  "sort": [{
    "ts": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }]
}
```

to return objects like:

```
{
  "userId": 56,
  "eventName": "synchronizationStart",
  "ts": 1553082491729,
  "deviceId": "0C1EEEF3FB9D406FB06451F74A01290B",
  "userAgent": "x86_64 - iOS 12.1 (3.5.0 build 1)"
}
```

but the "sort by ts asc" is not taken into consideration.

I mapped ts with a date format. (I also try with an integer).

Is a good practice exists to use the sort on a timestamp ?

my mapping (`events/_mapping`): https://pastebin.com/91yUN0Ax

and the raw output output (`events/_search`): https://pastebin.com/AZbKYyw5

Comment: Query looks correct and it should work as expected i.e. sorts correctly. Could you share the `mapping` details. Also could you confirm that all of your documents have the `ts` field? Using sort on `timestamp` is a very common use case.

Comment: @kamal I have the following mapping: https://pastebin.com/91yUN0Ax `events/_mapping` and the raw search output `events/_search` https://pastebin.com/AZbKYyw5 Thx a lot

Comment: I've created the mapping and ingested the data you've shared. Query works as expected. The data gets sorted too correctly. What version of ES are you using? I've tried on 5.x version.

Comment: @kamal version 6.3.2

Comment: one last thing, could you share me the result of your query. Query works well in my machine and it works correctly.

Comment: @Kamal I shared it in the second pastebin

Comment: could you change your mapping and add this and see if it works. `"ts": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis"
          }` Do note that you would require to re-create the index and re-ingestion the documents.

Comment: @kamal I removed the sort from the body query and add it in the uri : `events/_search?size=9999&sort=ts:desc` and that's work fine. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the sort from the body query and add it in the uri: `events/_search?size=9999&sort=ts:desc`